# Not sure why URL isn't being passed into a scraper of RSS feeds

Tags: pandas, feedparser

Just want to scrape news feeds from RSS.

```
import feedparser
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

archive = pd.read_csv("national_news_scrape.csv")

# Your list of feeds
feeds = [{"type": "news","title": "BBC", "url": "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/uk/rss.xml"},
        {"type": "news","title": "The Economist", "url": "https://www.economist.com/international/rss.xml"},    
        {"type": "news","title": "The New Statesman", "url": "https://www.newstatesman.com/feed"},    
        {"type": "news","title": "The New York Times", "url": "https://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml"},
        {"type": "news","title": "Metro UK","url": "https://metro.co.uk/feed/"},
        {"type": "news", "title": "Evening Standard", "url": "https://www.standard.co.uk/rss.xml"},
        {"type": "news","title": "Daily Mail", "url": "https://www.dailymail.co.uk/articles.rss"},
        {"type": "news","title": "Sky News", "url": "https://news.sky.com/feeds/rss/home.xml"},
        {"type": "news", "title": "The Mirror", "url": "https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/?service=rss"},
        {"type": "news", "title": "The Sun", "url": "https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/feed/"},
        {"type": "news", "title": "Sky News", "url": "https://news.sky.com/feeds/rss/home.xml"},
        {"type": "news", "title": "The Guardian", "url": "https://www.theguardian.com/uk/rss"},
        {"type": "news", "title": "The Independent", "url": "https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/rss"},
        #{"type": "news", "title": "The Telegraph", "url": "https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/rss.xml"},
        {"type": "news", "title": "The Times", "url": "https://www.thetimes.co.uk/?service=rss"}]

# Create an empty DataFrame to store the news
news_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['source', 'title', 'date', 'summary', "url"])

# For each feed, parse it and add the news to the DataFrame
for feed in feeds:
    print(f"Scraping: {feed['title']}")
    d = feedparser.parse(feed['url'])
    for entry in d.entries:
        # Some feeds do not have 'summary' field, handle this case
        summary = entry.summary if hasattr(entry, 'summary') else ''
        url = entry.link
        # Add the news to the DataFrame
        news_df = news_df.append({'source': feed['title'],
                                  'title': entry.title,
                                   "url": url,
                                  'date': datetime(*entry.published_parsed[:6]),
                                  'summary': summary,
                                  }, ignore_index=True)

combined = pd.concat([news_df, archive]).drop_duplicates()

# Save the DataFrame to a CSV file
news_df.to_csv('national_news_scrape.csv', index=False)
```

Why doesn't it read the URL of an individual article?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided reads the URL of an individual article. The URL of each article is extracted from the `entry.link` attribute within the loop that iterates over the feed entries. The URL is then stored in the 'url' column of the `news_df` DataFrame using :

```py
url = entry.link
```

The URL is added to the DataFrame using the `news_df = news_df.append({...})` line within the same loop.

You are saving the scraped data to the `news_df` DataFrame, but you are not saving the `combined` DataFrame, which is created by concatenating `news_df` and `archive` DataFrames and removing duplicates. You may need to add this :

```py
combined.to_csv('national_news_scrape.csv', index=False)
```